# Getting Rail4 asset-pipeline to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

My css & images are not making it to heroku. But I did what their tutorial said to do.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/assets
git commit -m "assets added"
```

Then I heroku push and get

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
```

so my assets pushed but there is still no css images or anything on my heroku app. Any ideas?

Comment: try setting the option to serve static assets to true in the production config.

Comment: @jvnill how do i do that?

Comment: I put " config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true " But I got an error "undefined local variable or method `config'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try don't send your assets to heroku.

Remove public/assets from git:

```
git rm -r public/assets
git commit -m "Remove assets"
```

If still not working, on config/environments/production.rb set:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

You also can try, on config/environments/production.rb set:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: This solution on the surface will make things behave as desired. But it is slow, and thus should not be done. You should not do `config.assets.compile = true` because it means it the server compiles on the fly, resulting in things becoming slow.

Answer (score 0):

**[Heroku needs to have static assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)**, so each time you push to Heroku & change your assets, you should use this command:

```
rake assets:precompile
```